# This function is not registered in the lock list

Tags: monaca, angularjs

monacaのテンプレートファイルをちょっと修正しただけでエラーが表示されてしまい、
原因が特定出来ず困っております。
エラー自体は無視しても、他は動作するようなので、無視することも可能ですが、
なるべくならエラー表示されないようにしたいと考えております。

解決のヒントを頂けませんでしょうか。

実行手順
１．クラウド上で「Onsen UI最小限のテンプレート」からプロジェクトを作成
２．LocalKitにインポート
３．index.htmlを若干修正
４．LocalKitでプレビュー実行するとDeveloperツール画面にエラーが表示される。

■エラーログ

```
Error: This function is not registered in the lock list.
    at Object.DoorLock._unlock (loader.js:1450)
    at unlock (loader.js:1450)
    at Scope.$broadcast (loader.js:1444)
    at link.post (loader.js:1454)
    at invokeLinkFn (loader.js:1442)
    at nodeLinkFn (loader.js:1441)
    at compositeLinkFn (loader.js:1441)
    at compositeLinkFn (loader.js:1441)
    at compositeLinkFn (loader.js:1441)
    at loader.js:1441
```

■index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
        var module = angular.module('myApp',['onsen']);   // ← この行追加
    </script>
</head>
<!-- <body>  修正前  -->
<body ng-app="myApp">   <!--  ←この行修正 -->
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ons.bootstrap();
var module = angular.module('myApp',['onsen']);
```

ここの2行が競合しているのではないかと思います。
`angular.module('myApp',['onsen'])`
の方法でOnsenUIを使用するのであれば、
`ons.bootstrap();`
は削除してしまって良いと思います。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございました。 ons.bootstrapの削除で解決しました。
初歩的なところでつまづいてしまって、申し訳ありませんでした。